# giving SFTP server credentials from another text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysftp

I wrote a python script below to make a SFTP connection to a server by giving server credentials like IP,USERNAME,PASSWORD from another text file. eventhough i am successful I don't think it is the best method to do it,Please suggest some suggestions so that i can improve the code

text file format:

127.0.0.1,jack,password

MY CODE:

```
import os
import pysftp
import socket
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
import time
import os.path
import shutil
import fileinput
import lock

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

f = open("text.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    words = line.split(',')
    IP=words[0]
    myUsername=words[1]
    myPassword=words[2]
    print(IP)
    print(myUsername)
    print(myPassword)

    with pysftp.Connection(host=IP, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        print("connection successful")
```

Comment: you need to close the file when you are done, or use with statement

Comment: any suggestion about taking values from the txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file format looks like csv you could use the csv module.

```
import csv
with open("text.txt", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

`row` is a list with ip,username,pass

> Example:

Textfile:

```
127.0.0.1,jack,password
127.0.0.1,jack2,password2
127.0.0.1,jack3,password3
```

Output:

```
> ['127.0.0.1', 'jack', 'password']
> ['127.0.0.1', 'jack2', 'password2']
> ['127.0.0.1', 'jack3', 'password3']
```

*Be carefull a password could contain a `,` in the string.
Anyway storing passwords in a text file isn't a good solution.*